# After updating product_sku and product_image haven't updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After updating product_sku and product_image haven't updated...
But other values are updated...

```
if (isset($_POST['update_product'])) {
        $product_id           =$_POST['product_id'];
        $product_name         =$_POST['proname'];
        $product_sku          =$_POST['prosku'];
        $product_price        =$_POST['proprice'];
        $product_height       =$_POST['proheight'];
        $product_width        =$_POST['prowidth'];
        $product_weight       =$_POST['proweight'];
        $product_category     =$_POST['procategory'];
        $product_description  =$_POST['prodesc'];
        $product_image        =$_POST['product_image'];
            $sql = "UPDATE  product ". " SET product_name='$product_name', product_price='$product_price',product_sku='product_sku',product_height='$product_height', product_width='$product_width',product_weight='$product_weight',product_category='$product_category',product_image='$product_image', product_description='$product_description' "."WHERE product_id=$product_id";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         if(! $result ) {
               die('Could not update data: ');
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
```

Comment: You want to read about [SQL injection](https://www.php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the level of "product_sku = 'product_sku'" you forgot '$' so you will have "product_sku = '$ product_sku'" for the image use "$ _FILE ['product_image'] "

Comment: Thanks,
But product image uploaded after using this code.. (reference here:https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)